# Explanation of a part of Azamer B'Shvochim

Tags: shabbat-songs

Can someone explain the end of the fourth stanza (bold below) of the song Azamer B'shvochim? 
יְחַבֵּק לַהּ בַּעְלַהּ
וּבִיסוֹדָא דִי לַהּ
דְּעָבֵד נְיָחָא לַהּ
**יְהֵא כָתֵשׁ כְּתִישִׁין**

Her husband embraces her; through this gathering which brings her joy, **will be utterly crushed**.

Who will be utterly crushed? Why?

Comment: whose translation are you using?

Comment: @vram chabad online

Comment: was that comment meant for me? I don't really go by Vram anymore, at least not since you joined...

Comment: yes it was, I saw others calling you that and i don't have the patience to try to copy+paste that other weird thing, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crush-ee referenced here is Dovid HaMelech who kabbalistically represents malchus, the feminine, receptive aspect. Dovid is described in the zohar as 'badchana d'malka', the jester or whipping boy of the king. As such it is Dovid who is being crushed and rejoicing in being able to serve his master even in this way.

Comment: Very interesting, I like this answer.

Answer (score 5):

The interpretation brought in [the Seder Z'mirot by Tzvi Yechezkel Michelsohn](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52061&pgnum=9), which is [R' Yaakov Emden's commentary](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42978&pgnum=308), is that The Shechina lovingly unites (so to speak) with the Jewish people, and this is a pleasure (Nachat Ruach) for th Shechina. This crushes the accusers.